# A software that sees the actual happenings in the computer memory?

Tags: vb.net, memory

Is there any software that can see the actual happenings inside a computer memory? Is it possible? I have a software that I developed and it consumes a lot of memory and I just want to understand why, then came the thought of a software that can see what happens inside the memory of a computer? I've done refactoring and unit testing several times but still consumes a lot..Is there anything on the web? I googled and currently don't have success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a memory checker/memory leak detector. Since you didn't specify a platform it'll be hard to make a specific suggestion, but on Linux you can use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and on Windows you can check out some of the tools [in this similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows).